# How to open another python file from tkinter in a specific condition(like user wins)

Tags: python, tkinter

According to my advisor, she wants me to give a more fancy window when the user wins. I asked whether there is a way to play gif on stack overflow before, and there is a way according to some people. Now I have finished writing the script for the gif which is going to play (actually I referred that from a website because my ability is limited):

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from itertools import count, cycle


class ImageLabel(tk.Label):
    def load(self, im):
        if isinstance(im, str):
            im = Image.open(im)
    frames = []

        try:
            for i in count(1):
                frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy()))
                im.seek(i)
        except EOFError:
            pass
    self.frames = cycle(frames)

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']
        except:
            self.delay = 100

        if len(frames) == 1:
            self.config(image=next(self.frames))
        else:
            self.next_frame()

    def unload(self):
        self.config(image=None)
        self.frames = None

    def next_frame(self):
        if self.frames:
            self.config(image=next(self.frames))
            self.after(self.delay, self.next_frame)
root = tk.Tk()
lbl = ImageLabel(root)
lbl.pack()
lbl.load('D:/Personal/Game/Win.gif')
root.mainloop()
```

Now I have seen that a class is defined, so can I add the class in `showframe` like `controller.showframe(ImageLabel)`?
The code for the last question:

```
class Q10(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!! Does group or period in the periodic table represent outer shell "
                                "electrons?",
                     font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Period",
                        command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Wrong...You can draw it out and see"),
                                         controller.show_frame(Failure), fail7()])
    button1.pack()

    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Group",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Success))  # Can I add the imagelabel class here?
    button2.pack()

    button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(Credits), give_up()])
    button3.pack()

def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):
    print(choice)
```

Comment: what exactly is not working. also as I mentioned You can use `import file` to simply run it

Comment: Is it like ```import image as something``` and embede the ```something``` into the ```controller.showframe()```

Comment: no You can just run a file by doing `import file_name`, Your suggestion will also run the file but just put the import in a function and call that function, if the file can run itself obvs

Comment: I have imported the file without the extension .py and it seems to be work, and I have embedded the module made by myself into the ```command=lambda:```. I will test to see if it works. If it doesn't, I will post the problem here.

Comment: Update: after embedding the module into ```command=lambda:```, the win gif shows first before the game. I imported by ```import Win as win```(which Win is my file name)

Comment: there is no need to use `as win` also can You show exactly how You implemented it? maybe shouldn't use lambda just define a new function that does: `import Win`

Comment: I imported ```Win``` module and implemented like this ```button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Group",
                            command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(Success), win])
        button2.pack()```, which win is my module name and when the user clicks the right button, the gif of win will show.

Comment: two things: first it isn't suggested to run multiple functions using lambda (so basically it is better to just define another function and run it), second don't import `Win` at the start because it will run it at start, import it like this `def open_file(): import Win` and then add this function to the button, tho it may cause issues (will try providing an answer)

Comment: actually the easiest way would be to just `from Win import ImageLabel` and then just pack it to the existing window or if You really want to have a separate window use `Toplevel`. If You do this don't forget to remove everything that may execute in the `Win` so everything that is not class is not necessary in this case

Comment: The ```import Win``` was grey at the end and when I put that function inside, it just showed an empty tk window.

Comment: That is the issue I mentioned but read my other comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232210/discussion-between-susie-xue-and-matiiss).

Answer (score 0):

This would be the `Win` file:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from itertools import count, cycle


class ImageLabel(tk.Label):
    def load(self, im):
        if isinstance(im, str):
            im = Image.open(im)
        frames = []

        try:
            for i in count(1):
                frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy()))
                im.seek(i)
        except EOFError:
            pass
        self.frames = cycle(frames)

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']
        except:
            self.delay = 100

        if len(frames) == 1:
            self.config(image=next(self.frames))
        else:
            self.next_frame()

    def unload(self):
        self.config(image=None)
        self.frames = None

    def next_frame(self):
        if self.frames:
            self.config(image=next(self.frames))
            self.after(self.delay, self.next_frame)
```

And in the main file at the beginning `from Win import ImageLabel` and then define a function like this (tho You may want to change parent for example to a frame or another window (in which case use `Toplevel`) but it is up to You):

```
def func():
    lbl = ImageLabel(root)
    lbl.pack()
    lbl.load('D:/Personal/Game/Win.gif')
```

and then call this function in the button `command` (also as I mentioned it isn't the best practice to call multiple functions using lambda so You could also in the `func` for example add the `.showframe` function or whatever You had there so that they are in one place and in the command then You can just do `command=func`)